# Font color inconsistent for page break

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using package `csquote` for quote blocks, and putting it inside a `tcolorboxenvironment` within the package `tcolorbox`.
When it comes a page break, I find some font style inconsistent, in my case, it is font color rather `itshape`:

[image: font color changes from gray to blak]

I believe that is caused by the `tcolorboxenvironment` settings.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
    \renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\itshape\color{gray}}
    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{blanker, breakable, parbox=false, before
skip=16pt,after skip=16pt, borderline
west={2mm}{0mm}{gray}, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, before upper={\parindent=25pt},
right=1\parindent, }
\newenvironment{note}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{20pt}{0mm}}
{\end{adjustwidth}}




\begin{document}


\begin{note}
Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
\end{note}


Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the solution to your code, but you can define a `tcolorbox` with a geometry similar to your quotes without extra packages. In this case, the color is esqual in every fragment.

Following code shows something similar to original quotes, but may be the geometry needs some adjusting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%    \renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\itshape\color{gray}}
    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{blanker, breakable, parbox=false, before
%skip=16pt,after skip=16pt, borderline
%west={2mm}{0mm}{gray}, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, before upper={\parindent=25pt},
%right=1\parindent, }
%\newenvironment{note}
%{\begin{adjustwidth}{20pt}{0pt}}
%{\end{adjustwidth}}


\newtcolorbox{borderquote}[1][]{%
 enhanced, breakable,
 blanker,  borderline west={2mm}{0mm}{gray},
 top=5pt, bottom=5pt,
 before skip=16pt, after skip=16pt,
 fontupper=\itshape,
 colupper=gray,
 title={Quote block:},
 coltitle=black,
 left=14mm,
 right=14mm,
 lefttitle=5mm,
 toptitle=2mm
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{borderquote}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{borderquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `use color stack` (I used red to get a better screenshot):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
    \renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\itshape\color{red}}
    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{blanker, breakable, parbox=false, before
skip=16pt,after skip=16pt, borderline
west={2mm}{0mm}{gray}, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, before upper={\parindent=25pt},
right=1\parindent,use color stack }
\newenvironment{note}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{20pt}{0mm}}
{\end{adjustwidth}}




\begin{document}


\begin{note}
Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
\end{note}


Quote block:
\begin{displayquote}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}


\end{document}
```

[image]